# Arduino ADK Connection error

Tags: android, arduino, adk

i'm trying to learn how to use arduino mega adk with my android. 
I made a simple code just to check the connection, and it is returning a error.

> Device addressed... Requesting device descriptor. found possible
>   device. swithcing to serial mode Data packet error: 5could not read
>   device protocol version

My code is this:

> ```
> #include <Max3421e.h>
> #include <Usb.h>
> #include <AndroidAccessory.h>
>
> AndroidAccessory acc("Google, Inc.",
>            "DemoKit",
>            "DemoKit Arduino Board",
>            "1.0",
>            "http://www.android.com",
>            "0000000012345678");
> void setup();
> void loop();
>
> void setup()
> {
>   Serial.begin(9600);
>   Serial.print("\r\nStart");
>   acc.powerOn();
> }
>
> void loop()
> {
>   byte msg[3];
>
>   if (acc.isConnected()) {
>                 Serial.print("Accessory connected. ");
>       int len = acc.read(msg, sizeof(msg), 1);
>                 Serial.print("Message length: ");
>                 Serial.println(len, DEC);
>         }
>
>   delay(100);
> }
> ```

Comment: Hello Henrique, I am getting same error. have you solved this?

Comment: Hi Amol. I couldn't solve the error already because i was out for some days, but i got some answers from the USB Host Shield library's developer: http://www.circuitsathome.com/mcu/usb-host-shield-library-version-2-0-released/comment-page-3#comment-23773